# Z Buffer Algorithm-Visible Surface Determination

Tags: algorithm, graphics, theory, surface

I have the following explanation of Z-Buffer Algorithm

[image]

There is a pseudocode for the algorithm from the same source

[image]

In the explanation they are saying that - if the z value in the image space is greater, then replace the corresponding z-buffer value but when it comes to the pseudo code they are doing the reverse.

Can some one tell me if i'm wrong?

Im reffering http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/education/GraphicsNotes/Z-Buffer-Algorithm.pdf

Comment: I haven't read the pdf document, but just upon inspecting the pseudocode, it looks as if the pseudocode is incorrect - simply because z-buffer[x,y] is initialized to minus infinity, it looks that the if condition z-depth < z-buffer[x,y] will never be true. So I would try to run the code with z-depth < z-buffer[x,y] being replaced by z-depth > z-buffer[x,y] and see if one gets the expected result.

Comment: @JohnDonn Thanks.. thats what i did ..

Comment: @JohnDonn Would you mind adding it as an answer,so that i can accept it.

Comment: Thank you, but mine is really not an answer. If you found it helpful, you may just upvote the comment.

Comment: @JohnDonn okay .......... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's only a matter of convention, how to compute the Z/depth. If you associate a left-handed frame to the scene (X to the right, Y up an Z pointing to the observer), the comparison is "greater". If you count Z as the depth from the  observer, the comparison is "smaller".

Comment: Have you seen the explanation and the pseudocode I have posted.In the explanation they are saying greater than but when it comes to the code .. its less than.

Comment: @techno: they probably mixed the conventions. You are able to fix this.